# Whatsapp Admin Messages

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is it possible to delete the messages that come up in group admin with a blue background showing admin activity?  e.g: date, admin added phone no/name, or someone left.  When you tap and hold these messages you just get 'Message ...'
    'Voice call ...'
    'Video call ...'
I have streams of these messages on my phone from various groups and would like to get rid of them.  I have asked google several times and this site seems my best bet.

Comment: its not possible to delete notification messages

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete them individually, but deleting the whole chat is a solution.